# Unable to install Angular CLI on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am trying to install angular cli on my Ubuntu machine by running `sudo npm install -g @angular/cli`. It progress half way and then it throws error.

I have tried executing `npm cache clean` and `npm cache verify` after getting those errors and it didn't help:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Can you try removing **`node_modules`** .

And then try **`npm install`**

or you can follow the **[`steps`](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions)** here to prevent permission errors.

Comment: remove *node_modules* from where?

Comment: @Benjamin in your app  folder

Comment: I am trying to install *angular-cli* globally. Regardless of my apps. In fact I am not in my app folder when trying to install it.